# How do I create dynamic user profile pages using params on expressjs like website.com/@username

Tags: node.js, express

This is what I have, my problem is other pages like website.com/settings don't render anymore

```
    router.get('/:@username',(req, res)) => {
        
        res.render('profile')

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not use `@`
However you can access it with `req.params`

```
router.get('/:username',(req, res)) => {
    console.log(req.params.username)
    res.render('profile')
}
```

You can access it with: `localhost:3000/myname` it should now log `myname`

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, I think my question wasn't clear enough, but I figured it out, I needed to put the @ before the colon